# UWP Xaml Password box allow only numbers

Tags: xaml, uwp, passwordbox

I want to add a passwordbox to my UWP app(Mainly use as a desktop application) which allows only numbers how can I achive this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to achive this.

Xaml:

```
                <PasswordBox
                x:Name="ConfirmPinNumber"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Width="100"
                Height="38"
                Padding="10,8,10,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="False"
                KeyDown="PasswordBox_KeyUp"
                MaxLength="8"
                PasswordRevealMode="Hidden" />
```

Xaml.cs:

```
 private void PasswordBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift).HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) ||
            !(e.Key >= VirtualKey.Number0 && e.Key <= VirtualKey.Number9 || e.Key >= VirtualKey.NumberPad0 && e.Key <= VirtualKey.NumberPad9 || e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Trying to add special characters using shift key and number keys handle from the below code.

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift).HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
```

Comment: It looks you have self answered, please don't forget mark yourself.